# Insert todays date into Access table using SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Im trying to use an SQL statement to insert the current date into an access table.

Ive got

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblImportedData (dtmReportDate) VALUES Now();"
```

This isnt working. Anybody know what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put `Now()` between brackets like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblImportedData (dtmReportDate) VALUES (NOW())
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put parenthesis around your list of values, even though there's only one column you're inserting into:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblImportedData (dtmReportDate) VALUES (Now());"
```

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, and because I came here looking for date, not datetime, if you need to enter the current date (as opposed to date and time) you can use:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblImportedData (dtmReportDate) VALUES (Date())"
```